# Ubuntu 12.10 usb installation problems :(

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 12.10 installation problem via usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234433/ubuntu-12-10-installation-problem-via-usb)

I had Windows 7, and I wanted to try Ubuntu 12.10. I downloaded the `.iso` file and used Universal USB Installer to make a bootable USB of Ubuntu. The installation was successful. I restarted my laptop to complete the installation and then, I got a black screen with white letters showing something like

OK, I will write now the whole message:

..........................................................
     Intel UNDI, PXE-2.1 (build 083)
     Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation

```
 This product is coverd by one or more of the following patents:
 US5, 307,459,   US5,434,872,  US5,732,094,  US6,570,884,   US6,115,776
 and US6, 327, 625

 Realtek PCIe GBE Familly Controller Series v2.35 (06/14/10)
 PXE-E61: Media test fallure, check cable

 PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.
```

............................................................

This is the message, and appears for about 2 sec and the laptop restarts and this goes again and again.

When I put my USB back and click on `Try Ubuntu` before installing, I can see that my HDD is not empty. I can see that Ubuntu is installed, but wont start.

Also I check my bios and my priority for boot are set 
1.HDD
2.DVD
3.USB
4.PCI Lan

My laptop is a Lenovo B570.

Comment: SOLUTION:

 1. Your harddrive needs to be in MBR format, also Disable UEFI on laptop bios. Since, 12.04 Grub 1.99 wont know how to write BOOT FILE in this mode.
 2. I formated my HDD from GPT to MBR with help of MiniTool Partition Wizard 7 Bootable USB.
 3. Start installation again, sda1 ext4 partition with 100GB. path: /
 4. Swap base: 4296MB
 5. Rest space formated with ext4, PATH: /home

Answer (score 0):

The bad news: I can reproduce this as described above.

My description of the problem: With an Lenovo B570 notebook it is possible to boot the Ubuntu 11.10 AMD64 64bit CD and (supposedly) install it successfully. I did a clean install giving all hard disk space to Ubuntu, deleting Windows. However upon reboot the operating system does not come up, but booting from network is tried and "PXE-E61 Media test failure, check cable PXE-M0F Exiting PXE ROM" (if no ethernet cable is attached) is displayed. After 5 seconds you can choose to boot from HDD/CD/LAN, but choosing HDD will bring you back to where you started.

**Installing the 32bit version with exactly the same steps results in a fully boot-able system, no tweak required.**

The good news: Some background information, albeit no real solution.

I am convinced that this is not really related to the selected architecture (64bit vs. 32bit), but an issue with the bootloader installed by Ubuntu. With the 64bit version Ubuntu tries to use a uEFI setup, but what it creates does not work, and from a first inspection should not even work.
The 32bit version does not even try to use uEFI but goes with a master boot record (MBR), and things work the way it is used.

I tried to install the 64bit version with manual formatting of the disk MBR + MSDOS partition table, and replacing grub-efi* with grub-pc after the installation. In theory this should have worked and resulted in a boot-able system, but in my test it did not.

Comment: Nope .. that is not helping. My HDD is first on the list, and boot form network is at last place.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing Grub from the installation media.

Comment: I cant, because I can't eve get Ubuntu to boot.... The screen flash, restart, flash ....

Comment: Go to try Ubuntu, open up the terminal and type sudo grub-install /dev/(your device here)

Answer (score 0):

**"Here some people affected by same problem, and they suggest to install 32 bit Ubuntu"**

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11545713

My description of the problem: With an Lenovo B570 notebook it is possible to boot the Ubuntu 11.10 AMD64 64bit CD and (supposedly) install it successfully. I did a clean install giving all hard disk space to Ubuntu, deleting Windows. However upon reboot the operating system does not come up, but booting from network is tried and "PXE-E61 Media test failure, check cable PXE-M0F Exiting PXE ROM" (if no ethernet cable is attached) is displayed. After 5 seconds you can choose to boot from HDD/CD/LAN, but choosing HDD will bring you back to where you started.

Installing the 32bit version with exactly the same steps results in a fully boot-able system, no tweak required.

The good news: Some background information, albeit no real solution.

I am convinced that this is not really related to the selected architecture (64bit vs. 32bit), but an issue with the bootloader installed by Ubuntu. With the 64bit version Ubuntu tries to use a uEFI setup, but what it creates does not work, and from a first inspection should not even work.
The 32bit version does not even try to use uEFI but goes with a master boot record (MBR), and things work the way it is used.

I tried to install the 64bit version with manual formatting of the disk MBR + MSDOS partition table, and replacing grub-efi* with grub-pc after the installation. In theory this should have worked and resulted in a boot-able system, but in my test it did not.

Comment: Ok Daniel but I have 6Gb of RAM. With Fedora 17 I had no problems. Also thanks, I will see what I can do now

Comment: Is Fedora 17 use a uEFI setup?

Comment: I think no ...  I am not sure