# Ubuntu does not load after installing it alongside Windows

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I chose to install 'alongside windows 7'.

After installation and restart, Windows 7 loaded but there is no sign that Ubuntu is actually installed.

Windows 7 is installed in `hdd0`, boots in legacy mode (only 1 HD in machine), UEFI secure boot is disabled.

I don't see anything on UEFI boot.

Partitions on my 1TB HDD:

- 100MB ntfs (win 7 installation made it automatically)
- 200GB NTFS (Win 7 partition)
- 4 GB Partition (I don't know what fs type)
- rest all unallocated

Edit: Yesterday I deleted the unused 4 gb partition current OS is running on live usb fat 32

The result of `fdisk -l`

[image]

Result of `sudo parted -l`

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you started the live CD but did not install Ubuntu? Since... 'unallocated' means non-formatted and without formatting something to ext3 or ext4 you can not install Linux.

Comment: I did installed it. It gave me 3 options<br/> (1)alongside win7<br/>(2)replace win7<br/>(3)something else( for repartitioning ,formatting, swap, ext drive etc.) i chosed alongside win 7.

Comment: Can you boot from the Live CD, and start `Disk Utility` to see if the rest of the data is really unallocated?

Comment: What did you install first, `Windows` or `Ubuntu`?

Comment: windows 7 was installed 1st

Comment: Then it's time to follow Gerhard Burger suggestion

Comment: Can you show us the output of `sudo parted -l` also?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't install it via [WUBI](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)? Because if that's the case, your whole Ubuntu install will be inside your NTFS partition, in a file.

Comment: I booted my pc to usb 4gb drive in uefi mode, then selected install alongside windows. This isnt wubi I guess

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Reinstall GRUB2 to the MBR, either:

- with [the instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)<sup>*****</sup>, or
- (if you prefer) using [any of these methods](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System).

<sup>***** This should fix the problem even though in this case it was not caused by a recent installation of Windows, see below.</sup>

### Explanation

You're installing alongside Windows 7 (not Windows 8 or later) and there's no reason to believe this is a UEFI system (no ["Secure Boot"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_boot#Secure_boot)). Therefore, we should expect that the cause of this problem is the *usual* cause of Ubuntu failing to boot after being installed as a fully-fledged (i.e., non-Wubi) system.

*Sometimes Ubuntu's installer will not successfully install the GRUB2 boot loader to the Master Boot Record.* As I [answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/234492/22949) in [this related (but somewhat different) question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234433/ubuntu-12-10-installation-problem-via-usb):

> While most installations go without anything going wrong, this is
> actually one of the more common installation problems. It can occur if
> you manually tell the installer not to install GRUB to the master boot
> record of the first hard drive, if it identifies the first hard drive
> incorrectly (its idea of first isn't necessarily what the BIOS tries
> to boot first), if it thinks a suitable boot loader is already in
> place (and is wrong), and possibly for other reasons.
>
> Reinstalling the GRUB2 boot loader to the master boot record of the
> drive that the BIOS is trying to boot almost always solves this
> problem. When someone with a working Ubuntu system installs a Windows
> system alongside Ubuntu, the Windows installer will overwrite the
> master boot record with its own boot loader, which does not detect and
> provide an option to boot Ubuntu. That's what your situation has in
> common with that of users who've just installed Windows beside Ubuntu.

Comment: i got sudo blkid

Comment: I have posted the screenshot of fdisk -l using live ubuntu 12.04

Comment: posted sreenshot of parted -l