# How do I boot into Ubuntu (after installing, it still just boots to Windows)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows

I've successfully installed Ubuntu (or so I'm told) on my Dell laptop alongside a clean Windows XP install. When I turn on the computer it boots directly into Windows with no options given to boot into Linux. What am I missing?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: See also [Ubuntu does not load after installing it alongside Windows](http://askubuntu.com/q/237644/22949)

Comment: I had a post a while back http://linux.m2osw.com/booting that explained how I created a quintuple boot system. However, in general, you want to first install Ubuntu, not on the first partition, then install WinXP on the first partition. At that point Windows overwrite your boot sector. So you want to "repair" your GRUB loader so it can find Linux again.

Comment: The most scary thing about this question is "alongside a clean Windows XP install". Windows XP is officially obsolete since April 8, 2014 (although unofficially since the release of Ubuntu 4.10). You should really consider upgrading to a modern OS, i.e. just keep Ubuntu.

Comment: @AlexisWilke At least for the typical dual boot case, I very much disagree that it is at all preferable to install Windows *second* (though of course [it *can* be done that way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)). Installing Ubuntu after Windows *usually* yields a working Windows system, a working Ubuntu system, and a working GRUB installation that provides the user with an easy selection between the two on boot. Even in cases like the OP's where it *doesn't* and GRUB must be installed to the MBR manually, the total work is still less.

Comment: @EliahKagan, it could be that it works better today. I don't do dual boot anymore. I use virtualbox instead (I very rarely need MS-Windows, and with their new additional protections, I'm less and less interested by their shitty OS.) However, a while back, it seems that RedHat (which I don't use either anymore) would do something that would blow Windows away...