# I can't install ubuntu... it just boots to windows!

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside windows and it won't work. I go through the installation process and it says to remove installation media and close tray. Then press enter. When I do this the computer restarts like normal and then boots to windows!

Comment: Give more info on how you are installing and mention did you change your boot order or not.

Comment: As explained in [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/238025/22949) to [Ubuntu does not load after installing it alongside Windows](http://askubuntu.com/q/237644/22949), the solutions given in [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/22949) will usually fix this problem (even though it was not caused by a recent *Windows* installation).

Answer (score -1):

most ppl are smarter than me. But this is how I did it: log in in windows. go to unetbootin.sourceforge.net  download GParted, while you are at unetbootin, make a bootable cd, or usb (of 4 gb size at least) with Ubuntu 14.04 on it, then go back to windows desktop. take out cd, or usb and set it down beside you.  start GParted, and make a seperate partition for ubuntu. I split my HDD 50/50. when you are done with the partitions, close all programs, and then shut down computer. insert cd, or usb and restart computer (be sure to enable boot from cd or usb in bios) press F12 or F2 when given the option. if you did things right, you should boot from cd, or usb. you will then be able to install ubuntu onto the new partition on your HDD, from the cd or usb.  There are great articles on how to use GParted on the web or at unetbootin... I printed the article called "Using GParted" that is at unetbootin. it has screen shots and step by step instructions, to help get you up and running in no time. using_gparted.txt  by patrick. take my advice and learn all you can about GParted FIRST... and have fun

Comment: Are you saying this solved the specific problem of not being able to boot the newly installed Ubuntu system when it was installed in a different way? As far as I know, manual partitioning--or shrinking your Windows partition prior to starting installation--neither decreases nor increases the likelihood of Ubuntu's installer failing to configure GRUB correctly and install its loader to the boot device's MBR.

Comment: just to be nice :) then why did not you answer the question?

Comment: I don't know if (or how) what you're asking relates to [my comment above](http://askubuntu.com/a/526183?noredirect=1#comment716934_526183)... But the reason I haven't posted a separate answer here is that I think it's already answered in other questions on Ask Ubuntu (including [one that I did answer](http://askubuntu.com/q/237644)), so instead of posting a new answer I [posted a comment](http://askubuntu.com/q/524522?noredirect=1#comment716931_524522) about where I believe it's already been answered and voted to close the question as a duplicate of [one of them](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384).